# Como fazer windows form ocupar todo o espaço dentro da aplicação MDI?

Tags: c#, mdi

Eu estou criando um sistema de cadastro e gerenciamento, que funciona apenas com CRUD.
Toda a parte funcional do sistema esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas existe algo que tem me incomodado.
Estou utilizando aplicação em MDI, neste caso quando clico no menu superior, ele cria janelas menores dentro da aplicação, fazendo com que a longo prazo fique bagunçado.

Meu objeto é simplesmente fazer o seguinte: Clicar no menu superior, e o windows form ocupar 100% do espaço do MDI. Assim como quando clicar em outro menu, fechar a windows form atual e criar a outra pegando todo o tamanho da tela.
Alguém sabe me dizer como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Mas aí qual é o objetivo de se usar uma janela MDI?

Comment: Meu objetivo é para gerenciar as janelas da aplicação.
E falando nisto, eu descobri como usar ela em 100%, no caso é só ir em formBorderStyle, no menu de propriedades, e deixar com valor de "none", e também ir em windowState e deixar com valor de "maximize". Assim quando clica no menu, ele deixa ocupando 100% do espaço e sem bordas.

Comment: Mas ainda não sei como fazer para retirar os controles de minizar e maximizar que existe para estas janelas (no caso dentro do MDI aparece estas opções quando esta em 100% de  tamanho de tela), e também ainda não sei como fechar esta janela ao abrir outra pelo menu. Consegue me ajudar nisto?

Answer (score 1):

Eu encontrei a solução.

Para deixar o Form com 100% dentro de uma aplicação Mdi, é só ir nas propriedades do Form, e configurar o formBorderStyle com valor de "none", e também ir em windowState e deixar com valor de "maximize". Além disto também é necessário colocar o valor no campo ControlBox para false.

E por fim, para fechar qualquer Form aberto dentro do Mdi, é só utilizar:

```
foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
  f.Close();
}
```

Fazendo isto, ele fecha os Forms abertos, maximiza e desabilita os controles de minimizar/maximizar dentro do Mdi.

Esta foi minha solução.